# I added Sprite to CCArray, but how to get its member like getPosition() by CCObject?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

```
cocos2d::CCArray *arr;  
cocos2d::CCSprite *foo;  
arr->addObject(foo);

CCObject *item;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(arr, item)
{
    //how to get item->getPosition() ????
}
```

I know foo in arr is CCObject. And I want to know how to get their subclass' member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(static_cast<cocos2d::CCSprite*>item)->getPosition();
```

also if you store similar objects, take a look to CCMutableArray. It is a template-based container that will return instances of provided to template type without need to cast

Comment: thx. I know CCMutableArray, but it is deprecated in v2.0. http://cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Cocos2d-x_v20_Migration_Guide

Answer (score 1):

```
((cocos2d::CCSprite*)item)->getPosition()
```

You will use a lot type_casting in cocos2d-x